# Implementing OpenID authentication with Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, openid, google-apps

Very related to this question: [SSO, using Google Apps user database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597230/sso-using-google-apps-user-database?rq=1) but I'm wondering how the user Nil started off with his OpenID script.

Could anyone give some background on this? I'm not very familiar with OpenID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Apps Marketplace [Google Apps Platform Single Sign On](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/sso) overview provides all the information you need to get started. Since @Nils describes a Corporate Google Apps environment, it's very likely that this is where they went to start their implementation, since...

> For in-house apps developed with the Google Apps extensions console, implementing Single Sign-On is a strongly recommended best practice.

You'll find background information and links to existing OAuth libraries in a variety of languages.

You should also look at the [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity-toolkit/), which provides an API you can use to implement SSO for your web app, as well as a Javascript widget you can incorporate to make the task simple.